# NULL value in the "name" column of the "files" relationship adding a NOT NULL entry

Tags: c#, postgresql, entity-framework

I ran into such a problem that when I add an empty value to a foreign key, I get an exception: PostgresException: 23502: "NULL value in the "name" column of the "files" relationship adding a NOT NULL entry"
And it's not clear to me why the file adding table is called, because I'm passing an empty value to the card table. Please tell me what it could be
SQL table Card

```
CREATE TABLE Files
(
    id SERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
    name VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL,
    file bytea NOT NULL
);

CREATE TABLE Card
(
    id SERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
    numMK INT NOT NULL,
    id_file INT,
    FOREIGN KEY (id_file) REFERENCES Files (id)
);
```

And my code C#:

```
public partial class Card
{
    public int Id { get; set; } 
    public int Nummk { get; set; }
    public int? IdFile { get; set; }
    public virtual FilePdf IdFileNavigation { get; set; }
}

public partial class FilePdf
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public string Name { get; set; }

    public byte[] File1 { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<Card> Cards { get; } = new List<Card>();
}
```

Initialization С#:

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {

        modelBuilder.Entity<Card>(entity =>
        {
            entity.HasKey(e => e.Id).HasName("card_pkey");

            entity.ToTable("card");

            entity.Property(e => e.Id).HasColumnName("id");
            entity.Property(e => e.Nummk).HasColumnName("nummk");
            entity.HasOne(d => d.IdFileNavigation).WithMany(p => p.Cards)
                .HasForeignKey(d => d.IdFile)
                .HasConstraintName("card_id_file_fkey");
        });

        modelBuilder.Entity<FilePdf>(entity =>
        {
            entity.HasKey(e => e.Id).HasName("filepdf_pkey");

            entity.ToTable("files");

            entity.Property(e => e.Id).HasColumnName("id");
            entity.Property(e => e.File1)
                .IsRequired()
                .HasColumnName("file");
            entity.Property(e => e.Name)
                .IsRequired()
                .HasMaxLength(30)
                .HasColumnName("name");
        });

        OnModelCreatingPartial(modelBuilder);
    }
```

And the very addition of the card

```
            using (var db = new TrappinganimalsContext())
            {
                var card = new Card()
                {
                    Id = 1,
                    Nummk = 2312,
                    IdFile = null,
                };
                db.Cards.Add(card);
                db.SaveChanges();
             }
```

I will be very grateful for your help

Comment: check the generated query

Comment: how can i check?

Comment: `db.Database.Log = s => System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(s);`

Comment: Thank you so much! And what library does the property contain "Log"?

Comment: you can right click on Log and see its definition, check this https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.entity.database.log?view=entity-framework-6.2.0 are you able to find out issue?

Comment: you should respond

Comment: Thank you very much for your help. I decided to store empty values in the "File" entity

Answer (score 0):

you can use `db.Database.Log = s => System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(s);` to get the generated query to see what is wrong with your query.

If required you can store an empty value in place of null

Comment: У меня хоть и установлена "EF Core" 7 версии, но лог не работает. Спасибо огромное за помощь!